# how to use clang static analyzer in qt creator

Tags: c++, qt-creator, clang-static-analyzer

see this manual [Using Clang Static Analyzer](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-clang-static-analyzer.html) in Qt Creator manual

can someone tell me for to set up this?
I don't see this tab in analyzer settings in QtCreator and don't see the plugin in the list which can be used for this...

UPDATE: sorry, I see this is a commercial version only

Answer (score 2):

good news for Qt Creator users: clang static analyzer will be included into QtC community edition starting from version 3.7

Comment: [Qt Creator 4.0 Beta released](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/03/23/qt-creator-4-0-beta-released/)